# If a timewalker goes to a time before they were born, do they replace someone or do they add a new person to history?

Tags: a-discovery-of-witches

In *A Discovery of Witches*, some witches have the ability to travel in time. (They're called timewalkers or sometimes time-spinners.) The ability is confusingly described using an analogy to getting off one crowded train and then getting on another when there's room. What I don't understand is, how are they inserted in the new time?

In *Shadow of Night* (book 2), it seems to me that Matthew replaces his 16th century self, rather than existing in two copies. However, 1590 is four centuries before Diana is born, so she's obviously not replacing herself. Is she replacing someone else, who will go missing from Woodstock and six months later turn up in London, with no memory of the intervening period? Is that what Aunt Sarah means when she describes showing up at work with no memory of making the drive as evidence of a timewalker being nearby? Because that seems... extreme.

> "It's happened to everybody. You drive to work and don't remember how you got there. Or the whole afternoon passes and you don't have a clue what you did. Whenever something like that happens, you can bet there's a timewalker nearby," explained Sarah.

(*A Discovery of Witches* chapter 39, p. 522)

If we posit that timewalkers *don't* replace someone who already exists in the time/place they're going to, how do we explain Matthew? Did he actually exist in two versions in winter and spring of 1590-1591? If so, how did the spymaster not get hopelessly confused? Or do people only replace themselves if they were already alive, otherwise they get added? Is this a choice the timewalker can make (just maybe Diana doesn't know how yet)?

Time travel hurts my brain...

Comment: Temporal mechanics gave me a headache tomorrow.

Comment: This book seems to obey the Quantum Leap school of time travel, e.g. a jumbly mish-mash of ill-though-out nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

(Don't mind me, just re-reading things the third time...)

**If a person already exists in that time, he (or she) replaces himself**:

> "He said you were sitting by the fire drinking wine one moment and gone the next," Gallowglass reported. [...]
>   I closed my eyes in sudden understanding. The Matthew Roydon who had been in sixteenth-century Chester vanished because he was displaced by the Matthew who'd traveled here from modern-day Oxfordshire. When we left, the sixteenth-century Matthew, presumably, would reappear. Time wouldn't allow both Matthews to be in the same place at the same moment.

(*Shadow of Night* chapter 5, p. 60)

**Time travelers remember both versions of history**. When Diana takes Matthew back to their first night in the Bishop house, Matthew says:

> "You still have your bandage. It means that when we go back in time, we don't stop being who we are in the present or forget what happened to us here."

(*A Discovery of Witches* chapter 40, p. 542)

I don't have a clear-cut quote (yet?), but I believe that the **historical people who see the time-travelers only remember the second version of history** - there is no version of history where Gallowglass doesn't meet Diana in 1590, for example. This is why it's important that "Matthew Roydon" never returned from his trip to Scotland: 16th century Matthew would have had different memories of that fateful winter and spring than all his friends did.

I still don't know where Sarah's "lost afternoon" theory of timewalking fits in.